# WCF takes over controller/action URL creation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I've created a MVC5 site which also hosts a WCF API. using other blog suggestions I created these routes:

```
routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("AuthZ", new ServiceHostFactory(), typeof(AuthZ)));

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

So in my form/view, now I have this code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Authenticate", "Login"))
{
....
```

but instead of the form pointing to `/Login/Authenticate` it actually comes out like this:

```
<form action="/AuthZ?action=Authenticate&amp;controller=Login" method="post">
...
```

This also happens in all `Html.ActionLink` and other methods that dynamically generate URLs. When I remove the AuthZ route, it starts working properly. The help and support for this tech is so low, I actually don't even know what to try at this point. Any suggestions?

Note, if its of any importance, this is the service configuration in web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="AuthZBindingConfiguration">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="MetadataBehavior" name="soap.AuthZ">
            <endpoint address="/AuthZ" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="AuthZBindingConfiguration" name="MainWSBinding" contract="soap.IAuthZ" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MetadataBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: It depends in which context your form/view is generated. If you're currently in a request of /AuthZ... then this is the main route at the moment.
Try using the [overloaded version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492590(v=vs.98).aspx) specifing a controller name also

Comment: no, the invoked page/context is /login. The overload in `BeginForm` is the one using controller name (Login), I tried with and without it.